# D3.js Zoomable Sunburst - Filtering data throws errors

Tags: d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I am building on the "Zoomable sunburst with updating data" as found here:
http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/477c1bfb081b783f80ad

I have created a jsFiddle which runs the example fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/nyaw6nje/

As you can see, from the jsFiddle everything works fine.

I would like to add filtering in, to remove items that are too small. However, once I add filtering code in:

```
  var nodes = partition.nodes(root)
    .filter(function(d) {
        return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.001 radians = 0.05 degrees
     })
    ;
```

...and click on the 'Size' radio button the chart collapses down and hundreds of errors are written to the console log:

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute
>   d="MNaN,NaNA271.1088342345192,271.1088342345192 0 1,1
>   NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNA221.35943621178657,221.35943621178657 0 1,0 NaN,NaNZ"

This amended jsFiddle demonstrates the behaviour:

http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/by6aaxf0/1/

The only difference between the two fiddles is the filtering code.

**How can I filter down the results in the browser and avoid this error?**